# Are there other ways to get People?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

Note: I am referring to the **resource** People, *not* Survivors or Heroes.

While putting Fortnite on the backburner for a little bit (to allow time for bug fixes, etc), I have made sure to continue checking daily to collect Research Points, grab my daily rewards, and send off Expeditions. However, after about a week of this, I've run out of People, which are required to send any expeditions past the first few that just bring back wood and stone.

I know that saving Survivors during missions grants 3 (possibly varies based on where you are in the game, but since I've started checking, it's always been 3) People per Survivor saved, but is there any other way to get People? I can do the Survivor missions solo if I have to, but it'd be nice if there was an alternative, since I tend to ***always*** find Survivors who ask me to find their medkits on the other side of the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is the only *consistent* way to gain People. They are occasionally a timed bonus reward for some missions, but this is quite rare - I've only ever seen this once.

If you need more People, the best way to gain them quickly is by doing Save the Survivor missions, since each of those survivors (there are 15 in one mission) will grant you more People at the end.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that you don't have to save them yourself. If others are rescuing survivors during the mission you'll still get People as a reward. I've also gotten a wide range of people, not always increments of 3. (I'm ~power level 21 if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

You can now do expeditions to get a low number of people.